# Different response from API in Vercel Deployement v/s local

Tags: node.js, axios, fetch-api, vercel

I am the author of [Rettiwt-API](https://github.com/Rishikant181/Rettiwt-API), a library which scrapes data from the API used by Twitter Web App.

Now, for fetching data such as User/Tweet details, no login is required and it can be done by a guest token which is obtained by sending a post request to this endpoint: https://api.twitter.com/1.1/guest/activate.json, along with a Bearer token.

The problem is that when I send a request from a local environment using axios, the guest token is obtained as expected. But when I run the same request from a web app deployed on Vercel, which utilizes the library for fetching data from Twitter, I get this response:

```
{
    "message": "Request failed with status code 429",
    "name": "AxiosError",
    "stack": "AxiosError: Request failed with status code 429\n    at eL (/var/task/.next/server/chunks        /151.js:16:36057)\n    at Unzip.<anonymous> (/var/task/.next/server/chunks/151.js:18:8452)\n    at Unzip.emit (node:events:529:35)\n    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1368:12)\n    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)",
    "config": {
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        },
        "adapter": [
            "xhr",
            "http"
        ],
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": -1,
        "maxBodyLength": -1,
        "env": {},
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "authorization": "Bearer         AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAANRILgAAAAAAnNwIzUejRCOuH5E6I8xnZz4puTs%3D1Zv7ttfk8LF81IUq16cHjhLTvJu4FA33AGWWjCpTnA",
            "User-Agent": "axios/1.4.0",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, compress, deflate, br"
        },
        "method": "post",
        "url": "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/guest/activate.json",
        "data": null
    },
    "code": "ERR_BAD_REQUEST",
    "status": 429
}
```

What might be the problem here and is there any way to actually get the guest token?